# Bizarre problem with onmouseover events not playing sounds

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

Alright, I recently tried to add sound effects to my portfolio.  Everytime the user puts the mouse pointer over a tile representing one of my projects, it makes a sound.  Seems simple enough, right?  Well, I have a strange error.  The sounds on the first two panels don't play until the sound on one of the panels below them does.  IE I have to glide my mouse over "Austin Weather Monitor" or "Bomb Defuser" before the sounds for "Crystal Collector" or "Train Timer" play.  Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Portfolio</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <style>

  #content {
    display: none;
  }

  .thumbnail:hover {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color:#E67F18;
  }
</style>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

   </head>




<body onload="showStuff()">


    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Dennis Markham</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">About Me</a></li>
      <li class = "active"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<!-- <div class ="container">
<section class ="row">
<div class ="col-md-1">
</div>
<div class="col-md-10"> 
<a href = "https://dennismarkham.github.io/trainTime/"> <img class = "portfolio" src = "images/dummy_image.png" alt ="train simulator"><span class = "caption">Train Timer </span></img></a> 


<a href = "https://dennismarkham.github.io/week-4-game/"><img class = "portfolio" src = "images/dummy_image.png" alt ="crystal collector"></img></a>


<a href = "#"><img class = "portfolio" src = "images/dummy_image.png" alt ="coming soon..."></img></a>
</div>
<div class = "col-md-1">
    </div>
</section>
</div> -->
<div id = "content">


<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-1">
</div>

<h1 style="padding: 5px; display: inline; border-radius:25px;">Solo Endeavors</h1>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class = "col-md-2"></div>

  <div class="col-md-4" onmouseover ="crystal()">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="https://dennismarkham.github.io/week-4-game/">
        <img style = "height: 250px" src="images/crystal.png" alt="Crystal" style="width:100%">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Crystal Collector</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-4" onmouseover = "train()">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="https://dennismarkham.github.io/trainTime/">
        <img  style = "height: 250px" src="images/train2.png" alt="Train" style="width:100%">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Train Timer</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>

  <div class="col-md-4" onmouseover="boom()">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="https://dennismarkham.github.io/BombDefuser/">
        <img style = "height: 250px" src="images/bomb.png" alt="Bomb" style="width:100%">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Bomb Defuser</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4" onmouseover="thunder()">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="https://dennismarkham.github.io/trainTime/">
        <img  style = "height: 250px" src="images/weather.png" alt="Train" style="width:100%">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Austin Weather Monitor</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>

  <div class="col-md-4"  onmouseover="shutter()">
    <div class="thumbnail" >
      <a href="https://rphotogallery.herokuapp.com/">
        <img style = "height: 250px" src="images/camera.png" alt="camera" style="width:100%">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>React Photo Gallery</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">

  </div>


  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
</div>

<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-1">
</div>
<h1 style="padding: 5px; display: inline; border-radius:25px;">Group Work</h1>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class = "col-md-2"></div>


   <div class="col-md-4" onmouseover = "typing()">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="https://cacheualcorner.herokuapp.com/">
        <img src="images/CC.png" alt="Cache-ual Corner (chat room)" style="width:100%">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Cache-ual Corner</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
</div>

</div>
<script>
//QUESTIONS:
//-Train sound and magic sound


var trainSound = new Audio("train.wav");
  trainSound.volume = 0.2;

  var crystalSound = new Audio("crystal.wav");
  crystalSound.volume = 0.5;

   var shutterSound = new Audio("shutter.wav");
   shutterSound.volume = 0.4;

  var thunderSound = new Audio("thunder.wav");
  thunderSound.volume = 0.3;

  var boomSound = new Audio("boom.mp3");
  boomSound.volume = 0.3;

  var typingSound = new Audio("typing.wav");
  typingSound.volume = 0.3;

  function showStuff() {
    $("#content").fadeIn("slow");
}


 function train(){
  trainSound.play();
 }

 function crystal(){
  crystalSound.play();
 }

 function shutter(){
 shutterSound.play();
 }

 function thunder(){
  thunderSound.play();
 }

 function boom(){
  boomSound.play();
 }

function typing(){
  typingSound.play();
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this?  I've tried re-ordering the variables and the functions in the scripts but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you add `console.log()` calls to your play functions to narrow down the problem? Are you getting any errors? Are you positive all the sounds are loaded when you start hovering tiles?

Comment: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first."